# How to get user details after login via oauth?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, battlenet-api

Trying to understand how it works `oauth`

How to get authorized user details using [`Blizzard api`](https://develop.battle.net/documentation)?

```
import json
import requests

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
region = "eu"
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}
access_token_response = requests.post(f"https://{region}.battle.net/oauth/token", data=data, allow_redirects=False, auth=(client_id, client_secret))
access_token = json.loads(access_token_response.text)["access_token"]
api_call_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
}
api_call_response = requests.get(f"https://{region}.battle.net/oauth/userinfo", headers=api_call_headers)
```

Comment: whats wrong with what you have now?

Comment: does not output user details from `get request` and i dont know why